# What does "faite" in this context mean?

Tags: sens, adjectifs

[image]

In my interpretation, the meaning of that sentence is "my fortune is made", made as in successful, or something that makes Gargamel's life prosperous. Is it wrong?

And then since "faite" can be a form of an adjective and also a passive voice. I don't know which one suits it in this context. Is it considered as an adjective or not?

Comment: It bears close structural similarity to the expression "c'est (maintenant) **chose faite**".

Comment: Really quite an exact translation of "my fortune is made", both in terms of meaning and grammar.

Answer (score 4):

In this context, Gargamel is being very optimist and is making the claim that his fortune is already **realized** and that he will have a prosperous life thanks to the tree trunk made of gold.

Answer (score 3):

You are right. "Faite" is an adjective and it means that Gargamel is rich now.

Vous avez raison. "Faite" est un adjectif et cela signifie que Gargamel est maintenant riche.